# php binary to decimal

Tags: php, binary, decode, encode

I am connecting to an api that returns binary string data that I need to convert to decimal format with php.  The data comes across in four-part chunks like "66 50 235 133" and should translate to some value around 50.00 (not sure exactly what the decimal value should be, but should be close to 50).

So, I need to convert the binary string "66 50 235 133" to a decimal value around 50.

I have read the pack and unpack function pages on php.net, but am unsure if this is the correct function to use and which formats to use (signed/unsigned,endian,etc).  Thanks for any help you can offer or any help point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Might be:

```
$input = '66 50 235 133';
$value = unpack('g', implode('', array_map('chr', explode(' ', $input))));
// outputs -2.2117755600046E-35
```

Or:

```
$input = '66 50 235 133';
$value = unpack('G', implode('', array_map('chr', explode(' ', $input))));
// outputs 44.729999542236
```

Depending on the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

I suspect it's the later, if you think this number is close to 50.00.

Comment: @izupdewd What protocol are you trying to crack? :P